# Flutter blue plus is not working on release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

```
flutter run --release
Launching lib/main.dart on motorola one vision in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            3.6s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (6.6MB).

Flutter run key commands.
h List all available interactive commands.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
D/FlutterBluePlugin(20889): onAttachedToEngine
D/FlutterBluePlugin(20889): setup
D/FlutterBluePlugin(20889): onAttachedToActivity
E/flutter (20889): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(startScan, Field androidScanMode_ for j.e0 not found. Known fields are [private int j.e0.h, private k.b0$i j.e0.i, private boolean j.e0.j, private static final j.e0 j.e0.k, private static volatile k.a1 j.e0.l], java.lang.RuntimeException: Field androidScanMode_ for j.e0 not found. Known fields are [private int j.e0.h, private k.b0$i j.e0.i, private boolean j.e0.j, private static final j.e0 j.e0.k, private static volatile k.a1 j.e0.l]
E/flutter (20889):      at k.v0.n0(Unknown Source:72)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.v0.T(Unknown Source:655)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.v0.R(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.k0.e(Unknown Source:60)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.k0.a(Unknown Source:49)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.d1.d(Unknown Source:17)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.d1.e(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.z$a.z(Unknown Source:9)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.z$a.y(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.z$a.o(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (20889):      at k.a$a.n(Unknown Source:2)
E/flutter (20889):      at j.h.K(Unknown Source:10)
E/flutter (20889):      at j.h.C(Unknown Source:2)
E/flutter (20889):      at j.h.i(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (20889):      at j.d.a(Unknown Source:6)
E/flutter (20889):      at j.h.v(Unknown Source:49)
E/flutter (20889):      at j.h.d(Unknown Source:1544)
E/flutter (20889):      at y.j$a.a(Unknown Source:17)
E/flutter (20889):      at m.c.j(Unknown Source:18)
E/flutter (20889):      at m.c.k(Unknown Source:20)
E/flutter (20889):      at m.c.g(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (20889):      at m.b.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (20889):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter (20889):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (20889):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
E/flutter (20889):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7806)
E/flutter (20889):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (20889):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/flutter (20889):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
E/flutter (20889): , null)
E/flutter (20889): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607)
E/flutter (20889): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177)
E/flutter (20889): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20889): #2      FlutterBluePlus.scan (package:flutter_blue_plus/src/flutter_blue_plus.dart:145)
E/flutter (20889): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20889): #3      _httpConnectionHook.<anonymous closure> (dart:_http/embedder_config.dart:21)
E/flutter (20889): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20889):
```

*I am getting this error when I am trying to scan for devices*

But the application is running fine when I am running on debug mode
I am using only the flutter_blue_plus plugin  `flutter_blue_plus: ^1.1.2`

here is my flutter doctor

```
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.8.1/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on macOS 12.2 21D49 darwin-arm, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.8.1/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (9 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/shaikmuzammilahmed/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/shaikmuzammilahmed/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • motorola one vision (mobile) • adb-ZF6224N9MH-ZBFJSA._adb-tls-connect._tcp. • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome                                       • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.109

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in debug mode?

Comment: No, I am not getting any exceptions in debug mode , everything is working fine in debug mode

Comment: Ok, is `shrinkResources` enabled in `android/app/build.gradle`?

Comment: signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false

Comment: Have you added Proguard?
Please check here
https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus/issues/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines in your project build.gradle

=> [Project-Name]/android/app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you disable minify and shrinking, you will not obfuscate the code you release. You shouldn't recommend disabling these without also giving a warning. For a production app, this is not sufficient for the vast majority of people, even if it seems to work - the underlying issue should surely be fixed instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 14):

Tell ProGuard to ignore the flutter_blue(_plus) files.

1. Add a `proguard-rules.pro` file to your apps folder
2. Make sure the file is referenced in your apps `build.gradle` e.g. as this

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

3. Actually tell ProGuard what to ignore inside the `pro guard-rules.pro` file. Pick the line with the library you are actually using.

```
# for flutter_blue_plus
-keep class com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.** { *; }

# for flutter_blue
-keep class com.pauldemarco.flutter_blue.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian. Any recommendation for iOS ? I'm facing similar issue in iOS and it's random in my case.